# Tikz draw binary tree 4 level deep using child

Tags: luatex, tikz-trees

I need to make a 4 level deep binary tree, for now I have :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[binary tree layout]
    \node{a}
        child{node{b}
            child{node{d}
                child{node{h}}
                child{node{i}}
            }
            child{node{e}
                child{node{j}}
                child{node{k}}
            }
        }
        
        child{node{c}
            child{node{f}
                child{node{l}}
                child{node{m}}
            }
            child{node{g}
                child{node{n}}
                child{node{o}}
            }
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But compiled on Overleaf, some node are overlaid on each other (i and j)(m and n).
And it's not a binary tree at all x)

[image: Wrong binary tree]

I have also tried to add :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[binary tree layout]
```

But we still have a problem concerning the c node

[image: using]

Answer (score 1):

You have a blank line between your `b` node and your `c` node, which confused the parser. Removing that makes the tree you want. But you may want to consider using `forest` for trees instead, as the input syntax (a labelled bracketing) is much simpler.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[binary tree layout]
    \node{a}
        child{node{b}
            child{node{d}
                child{node{h}}
                child{node{i}}
            }
            child{node{e}
                child{node{j}}
                child{node{k}}
            }
        }
        child{node{c}
            child{node{f}
                child{node{l}}
                child{node{m}}
            }
            child{node{g}
                child{node{n}}
                child{node{o}}
            }
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{forest}
[a [b [d [h] [i]] [e [j] [k] ]][c [f [l] [m]][g [n][o]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]